# Cmd Opening a document that is on my desktop but in my language desktop is called\Pracovná plocha)

Tags: python, windows, file, cmd

it looks like my problem is with my folder placement.I have a program in python that opens another python file. When I use this command  `"os.system("redditapi.py")`   (H:\Pracovná plocha\bot\redditapi.py)It looks like it only reads until H:\Pracovná. Because it gives me this error 'H:\Pracovná' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. More insight:https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/ihtvxb/python_is_not_recognized_as_an_internal_or/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3. How could I solve this problem. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: simply forget `Pracovná plocha` and use folder without space in name - i.e `Pracovná_plocha`. Sometimes it is good also use names without native chars - ie. `Pracovna_plocha`. OR use english names `Desktop`

Comment: …perhaps you should learn to appropriately quote file paths so that spaces in their names do not cause an issue.

Comment: You're mixing up unrelated errors. Running `os.system("redditapi.py")` depends on finding "redditapi.py" in the working directory, which will vary according to how the script is executed. Apparently under VSC the working directory is " H:\Pracovná plocha\bot". OTOH, quoting is required when running the absolute path "H:\Pracovná plocha\bot\redditapi.py". Since you don't have command-line arguments, you can let the subprocess module add the outer quotes for you, e.g. `subprocess.call(r'H:\Pracovná plocha\bot\redditapi.py', shell=True)`.